# How can I group items in a list until a certain element is found?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Going to try my best to explain this.

Currently I am scraping [this web page](https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/olivia-rodrigo/drivers-license-chords-3504560) using Selenium. I am just trying to get the chords from the page so I am using this code:

```
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "_3PpPJ OrSDI"]'):
    print (elem.text)
```

but this makes them print in a long list.

The issue is I need them to be organized the way they are on the website.

For example:

```
[ Verse 1 ] 
G Em C G
[ Verse 2 ]
G Em C G
```

like this:
[image]

I'm not sure if I should use `following-sibling` or what. My full code is here bellow:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import pandas as pd
import time
from collections import Counter
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from cleantext import clean
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options() 
#options.headless = True
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

url6 = 'https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/olivia-rodrigo/drivers-license-chords-3504560'

driver.get(url6)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

try:
    verse_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("// span[contains(text(),\
    '[Verse 1]')]").text
    print(verse_1)
except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(1)

for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "_3PpPJ OrSDI"]'):
    print (elem.text)            

verse_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("// span[contains(text(),\
'[Verse 2]')]").text
print(verse_2)
```

Comment: Page html code please

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little. This should work out of the box:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url6 = 'https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/olivia-rodrigo/drivers-license-chords-3504560'

driver.get(url6)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

list_verses = []
for x in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(text(),'[Verse')]"):
    list_verses.append(x.text)

dict_attributes= {}
for x in list_verses:
    new_attr = []
    for elem in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//span[contains(text(),'{0}')]/following-sibling::span/span/span[@class = '_3PpPJ OrSDI']".format(x)):
        new_attr.append(elem.text)
    dict_attributes[x] = new_attr
for x in list_verses:
    print(x)
    print(", ".join(dict_attributes[x]))
```

This is the output:

```
[Verse 1]
G, Em, C, G, G, Em, C, G, C, G, C, G, Em, D, G, Bm7, C, C6, D, G, G, Em, C, G, C, G, C, G, Em, D, G, Bm7, C, C6, D, G, G, D/F#, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, C, G, C, G, Em, D, Bm7, D, C, C6, D, G, C, D, Em7
[Verse 2]
G, Em, C, G, C, G, C, G, Em, D, G, Bm7, C, C6, D, G, G, Em, C, G, C, G, C, G, Em, D, G, Bm7, C, C6, D, G, G, D/F#, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, C, G, C, G, Em, D, Bm7, D, C, C6, D, G, C, D, Em7
[Verse 3]
G, Em, C, G, C, G, C, G, Em, D, G, Bm7, C, C6, D, G, G, D/F#, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, Em, C, G, D, C, G, C, G, Em, D, Bm7, D, C, C6, D, G, C, D, Em7
```

Comment: This is currently printing out ALL the chords every time. I'm looking to have them separated by where each "Verse", and "Chorus" are in respect to the website.

Comment: ok, sorry. It's not immediate.